# no upper right icons with Ubuntu 12.10 and lightdm

Tags: 12.10, server, icons, lightdm

I have a Ubuntu 12.10 server running in which I have installed lightdm. Now lightdm can boot and I can log in, but when I see the screen, I don't see ANY top right icon. So I cannot logout I cannot do anything. See screenshot:

[image]

My video card is: "VGA compatible controller: Matrox Electronics Systems Ltd. MGA G200eW WPCM450 (rev 0a)". From what I can see, it doesn't allow one to have a bigger screen than 1024 * 768. I don't care about this because it is a server... Still, I care that I cannot see the icons.

Just to be sure it was not a screen resolution problem I run "sudo dpkg-reconfigure -phigh xserver-xorg" but the problem persists...

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Icon is there its just off screen. You need to adjust the overscan on your video driver. If you have installed the ATI driver there is the ATI Catalyst program that allows you to do that.

You can logout, just move your cursor beyond the screen and the menu will pop down when you press the mouse.

Comment: Hi. I have updated my question. I am with VNC so I cannot go beyond the screen with my VNC client....